# Maximizing the vertical distance from a repulsive time-varying barrier

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-system, optimal-control, nonlinear-dynamics

Continuing topic: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246825/multidimensional-obstacle-avoidance-in-ode-part-ii

Given dynamical system:

$\boldsymbol{x}=f(\boldsymbol{x},u,t)$

where $\vec{\boldsymbol{x}}={x_1...x_n}$ - state-space variables.

Suppose I have chosen some variable from $\vec{\boldsymbol{x}}$ and want it not to exceed some repulsive trajectory that changes over time when moving towards a steady state.

How to maximize the vertical distance $S$ from the repulsive time-varying barrier?

[image]

Comment: Maximizing the distance would mean that $x \rightarrow -\infty$. So that would mean you have to take $u$ such that the system is unstable. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @SampleTime I know that the system is coming to a final state and I know its upper limit (it must be negative, therefore, the upper limit is zero), but I do not know the lower one. Those. the vertical distance must somehow be maximized as it moves towards a steady state. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear to me... You are practically asking to make an arbitrary nonlinear system track an unknown point? That is way to general to give a useful answer, you will have to give more details. From your question it is not even clear what you are looking for. Is it $u$? Or is $u$ given? Your comment that the system reaches a steady state implies that $u$ is given because otherwise you could just take $u$ so that $x \rightarrow -\infty$ as I said. However, if $u$ is given then how can you maximize $S$, i.e. what are your decision variables?

Comment: @SampleTime Let's take system of ODE from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246166/tuning-the-optimal-control-synthesized-according-to-the-pontryagin-maximum-minim

Comment: @SampleTime This system passes from the initial state to the final state. Let's rephrase the problem: how to maximize the derivative of the variable $h$ during the transition to a steady state? The system can be influenced via a control signal $u$, but it is not set.